# UITextField LeftView, adding multiple buttons like Mail To:

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am creating an application that mimics an email client (it's email, but it looks that way to the end user with a few enhancements).  I am wanting to replicate the functionality of the To: field in the Mail app.  I have found that I can add views (Buttons) to the LeftView property of but if they add several reciepents then I have to handle wrapping etc.  I have seen this functionality in several apps and was hoping that there was a way that this could be achieved without having to roll my own and handle wrapping, removal by handling backspace in an empty textfield, etc.

If anyone has any suggestions/pointers, I would greatly appreciate it.